# urimatcher in android content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, static-initialization

I am new to Android. I went through the code of Android `ContentProvider` and I am a little bit confused with the `UriMatcher` because the statements within *static* will execute first. Here in the code inside `UriMatcher` there is a *static* block without having idea about `PROVIDER_NAME`. How can it use it because before `PROVIDER_NAME` is initialized the *static* block should run.

```
public class CustomContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = 
        "net.learn2develop.provider.Book";

     public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = 
        Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER_NAME + "/books");

     public static final String _ID = "_id";
     public static final String TITLE = "title";
     public static final String ISBN = "isbn";

     private static final int BOOKS = 1;
     private static final int BOOK_ID = 2;   

     private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
     static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "books", BOOKS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "books/#", BOOK_ID);      
     }
```

any help is greatly accepted...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Static initialization code runs in textual order. This includes static fields as well as static blocks.

`PROVIDER_NAME` is therefore already initialized when the static block executes